# Key Press Event does not work for FigureCanvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, events, canvas

I wanted to add a key press event  to my canvas.

Sadly, the reset function in my class ZoomOnWheel only gets called when I connect a button press event. I don't know why it does not work with key press events....
The function does not even get called.

I created a minimum example for you to try out and replicate it.

```
from tkinter import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import random
import math

class PlotWindow:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.master=frame
        self.master.title=("GUI Analysis")
        self.mainframe=Frame(self.master,padx="3",pady='3')
        
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))           #Position der widgets
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.fig_raw=plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
        self.ax=self.fig_raw.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.raw_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig_raw,self.mainframe)
        self.raw_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()
        
        no_of_balls=25
        x = [random.triangular() for i in range(no_of_balls)]
        y = [random.gauss(0.5, 0.25) for i in range(no_of_balls)]
        colors = [random.randint(1, 4) for i in range(no_of_balls)]
        areas = [math.pi * random.randint(5, 15)**2 for i in range(no_of_balls)]
        
        self.ax.scatter(x, y, s=areas, c=colors, alpha=0.85)
        
        self.raw_canvas.draw()
        self.scroll=ZoomOnWheel(figure=self.fig_raw, scale_factor=1.1)
    
import logging
import weakref

class MplInteraction(object):
    """Base class for class providing interaction to a matplotlib Figure."""

    def __init__(self, figure):
        """Initializer
        :param Figure figure: The matplotlib figure to attach the behavior to.
        """
        self._fig_ref = weakref.ref(figure)
        self._cids = []

    def __del__(self):
        self.disconnect()

    def _add_connection(self, event_name, callback):
        """Called to add a connection to an event of the figure
        :param str event_name: The matplotlib event name to connect to.
        :param callback: The callback to register to this event.
        """
        cid = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(event_name, callback)
        self._cids.append(cid)

    def disconnect(self):
        """Disconnect interaction from Figure."""
        if self._fig_ref is not None:
            figure = self._fig_ref()
            if figure is not None:
                for cid in self._cids:
                    figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
            self._fig_ref = None

    @property
    def figure(self):
        """The Figure this interaction is connected to or
        None if not connected."""
        return self._fig_ref() if self._fig_ref is not None else None

    def _axes_to_update(self, event):
        """Returns two sets of Axes to update according to event.
        Takes care of multiple axes and shared axes.
        :param MouseEvent event: Matplotlib event to consider
        :return: Axes for which to update xlimits and ylimits
        :rtype: 2-tuple of set (xaxes, yaxes)
        """
        x_axes, y_axes = set(), set()

        # Go through all axes to enable zoom for multiple axes subplots
        for ax in self.figure.axes:
            if ax.contains(event)[0]:
                # For twin x axes, makes sure the zoom is applied once
                shared_x_axes = set(ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax))
                if x_axes.isdisjoint(shared_x_axes):
                    x_axes.add(ax)

                # For twin y axes, makes sure the zoom is applied once
                shared_y_axes = set(ax.get_shared_y_axes().get_siblings(ax))
                if y_axes.isdisjoint(shared_y_axes):
                    y_axes.add(ax)

        return x_axes, y_axes

    def _draw(self):
        """Conveninent method to redraw the figure"""
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

class ZoomOnWheel(MplInteraction):
    """Class providing zoom on wheel interaction to a matplotlib Figure.
    Supports subplots, twin Axes and log scales.
    """

    def __init__(self, figure=None, scale_factor=1.1):
        """Initializer
        :param Figure figure: The matplotlib figure to attach the behavior to.
        :param float scale_factor: The scale factor to apply on wheel event.
        """
        super(ZoomOnWheel, self).__init__(figure)
        self._add_connection('scroll_event', self._on_mouse_wheel)
        
        self._add_connection('key_press_event', self.reset)
        
        self.scale_factor = scale_factor

    @staticmethod
    def _zoom_range(begin, end, center, scale_factor, scale):
        """Compute a 1D range zoomed around center.
        :param float begin: The begin bound of the range.
        :param float end: The end bound of the range.
        :param float center: The center of the zoom (i.e., invariant point)
        :param float scale_factor: The scale factor to apply.
        :param str scale: The scale of the axis
        :return: The zoomed range (min, max)
        """
        if begin < end:
            min_, max_ = begin, end
        else:
            min_, max_ = end, begin

        if scale == 'linear':
            old_min, old_max = min_, max_
        elif scale == 'log':
            old_min = np.log10(min_ if min_ > 0. else np.nextafter(0, 1))
            center = np.log10(
                center if center > 0. else np.nextafter(0, 1))
            old_max = np.log10(max_) if max_ > 0. else 0.
        else:
            logging.warning(
                'Zoom on wheel not implemented for scale "%s"' % scale)
            return begin, end

        offset = (center - old_min) / (old_max - old_min)
        range_ = (old_max - old_min) / scale_factor
        new_min = center - offset * range_
        new_max = center + (1. - offset) * range_

        if scale == 'log':
            try:
                new_min, new_max = 10. ** float(new_min), 10. ** float(new_max)
            except OverflowError:  # Limit case
                new_min, new_max = min_, max_
            if new_min <= 0. or new_max <= 0.:  # Limit case
                new_min, new_max = min_, max_

        if begin < end:
            return new_min, new_max
        else:
            return new_max, new_min

    def _on_mouse_wheel(self, event):
        if event.step > 0:
            scale_factor = self.scale_factor
        else:
            scale_factor = 1. / self.scale_factor

        # Go through all axes to enable zoom for multiple axes subplots
        x_axes, y_axes = self._axes_to_update(event)

        for ax in x_axes:
            transform = ax.transData.inverted()
            xdata, ydata = transform.transform_point((event.x, event.y))

            xlim = ax.get_xlim()
            xlim = self._zoom_range(xlim[0], xlim[1],
                                    xdata, scale_factor,
                                    ax.get_xscale())
            ax.set_xlim(xlim)

        for ax in y_axes:
            ylim = ax.get_ylim()
            ylim = self._zoom_range(ylim[0], ylim[1],
                                    ydata, scale_factor,
                                    ax.get_yscale())
            ax.set_ylim(ylim)

        if x_axes or y_axes:
            self._draw()

    def reset(self, event):
        print(event.key)
        x_axes, y_axes = self._axes_to_update(event)
    
        for ax in y_axes:
            ax.set_ylim(0,1)
            print("")
        for ax in x_axes:
            ax.set_xlim(0,1)
        self._draw()
    
    
root=Tk()
root.title('CARS Analyser')
root.geometry("1920x1080")
Var=PlotWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with `matplotlib FigureCanvasTkAgg` so this may be way off as I'm just looking at canvas, assuming they are related.

Normally a canvas or canvas widget does not get focus even when clicked on which means they will not react if you bind them to `<Key>` or `<KeyPress>`.

So, what is it that you want to do? Select an item on the canvas and then have it respond to `<KeyPress>`? I'm including an example of how this may be done:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white')
canvas.pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=True, fill='both')

widgets = []
widgets.append(canvas.create_rectangle(120, 70, 160, 110, fill='black'))
widgets.append(canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20, 60, 60, fill='black'))
selected = None

def canvas_button(event=None):
    global selected
    try:
        current = event.widget.find_withtag("current")[0]
        if current == selected:
            canvas.itemconfig(current, fill='black')
            selected = None
        else:
            canvas.itemconfig(selected, fill='black')
            canvas.itemconfig(current, fill='red')
            selected = current
    except IndexError:
        # Clicked outside all canvas widgets
        pass

def canvas_key(event=None):
    if selected != None:
        canvas.itemconfig(selected, fill='blue')

root.bind('<Key>', canvas_key)
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', canvas_button)

root.mainloop()
```

Does this work for you?